# Weird behavior reading float vector from binary file

Tags: c, arrays, fopen, binaryfiles, fread

I'm putting a float32 array in a binary file using python to analyze it in C. For that, I'm using this python code:

```
'''python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=500

signal=np.arange(0,N)


#generating binary array
myarr=np.array(signal, dtype='float32')
myarr=myarr.tobytes(order='C')

#creating file.bin
with open('file.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(myarr)

#recovering the data
with open('file.bin', 'rb') as f:
    recAr=f.read()

recAr=np.frombuffer(recAr, dtype='float32')
print(recAr.size)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(signal)
plt.show()
'''
```

Then I'm reading it in C using this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


//Read a float vector from a binary file
float * readVector(int v_size, char file_name[]){
  float *my_floats=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*v_size);
  //opening file
  FILE *file_to_read = fopen(file_name, "r");

  if (file_to_read == NULL){
    printf("File would not open!\n");
  }
  //read binary
  //size_t fread ( void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );
  fread(my_floats, sizeof(my_floats[0]), v_size, file_to_read);

  fclose(file_to_read);

  return my_floats;
}

int main(void){

  int v_size=500;
  float *array=readVector(v_size, "file.bin");

  for(int i=0; i<v_size;i++)
    printf("%d - %f\n", i, array[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

But what I get is really strange. For small array sizes, everything goes ok, if N=50, I read it all fine, but if it's bigger, like 500, I can just read the first 100 ok, and then all the others goes wrong, most of them are read as 0.000. And if the data in signal is different, like a sine wave, I can read fewer good numbers. On the other hand, if I read it in python, it goes ok, and all the numbers in the array are right.

I really don't know what is happening.

Comment: ....because if the default opening mode is text `"t"` then there can be newline conversions on some systems.

Comment: That worked. In the documentation I've read about fopen, there was no option 'b', I thought that it was all opened in  binary mode, and what really mattered was the function I used to read it. Thank you!